# Swift| How To change the sound of Push notification to other system sound?

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, payload, userinfo

I'm kind of stuck with this issue. I have a working Push Notification in my app, and i'm trying to let the user to choose his own sound (All sounds are from iPhone built in sounds - kind of 'whatsapp') for a specific push notification.
the Payload i'm getting is something like

```
aps: {
alert = Message Type 1;
badge = 1;
sound = "default";
}
```

now in my app the user has three types of Push Notification, and I let the user choose which ringtone/Sound he wants for a certain push, after he choose I've saved his choice in NSUserDefaults.

my problem is that I Don't know how override the default sound in my userInfo and make a new Notification with a different sound that I saved in the NSUserDefaults. 
I did it easily on Java, but it's so different with Swift and the way it's work with IOS.
Would be grateful, If anyone can shade some light on the subject.